# Unable to create wallet due to issuer issue

Tags: horizon, issuing

All of sudden I am getting the following error on TestNet. Issuer Address is **GCZDLM6KBK7P42JB6ONIZNYXE24G72PWUXLOZBOLE5EEGOC2FUKKIN4R**

```
Creating Wallet for User with id 39
GDUOAIISLPGB6EZS4TLPTUWZD33EI6JMTONOYT7KPJVTFNKEVZUC73JZ SK5
Funding Account..
Establishing trust-line for the account GDUOAIISLPGB6EZS4TLPTUWZD33EI6JMTONOYT7KPJVTFNKEVZUC73JZ. Please wait!!
{'type': 'https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed', 'title': 'Transaction Failed', 'status': 400, 'detail': 'The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html', 'extras': {'envelope_xdr': 'AAAAAOjgIRJbzB8TMuTW+dLZHvZEeSybmuxP6nprMrVErmgvAAAAZAACTZMAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAWQ2hhbmdlIFRydXN0IE9wZXJhdGlvbgAAAAAAAQAAAAEAAAAA6OAhElvMHxMy5Nb50tke9kR5LJua7E/qemsytUSuaC8AAAAGAAAAAVNJTAAAAAAAsjWzygq+/mkh85qMtxcmuG/p9qXW7IXLJ0hDOFotFKQAAAALpDt0AAAAAAAAAAABRK5oLwAAAEDz+CxbPtsas14FfMePhVv3ClJM+ErlaII8YNFOodIFS8pblrngKDePwXIME/uNHT8VO+gxNOkkhBrjQ5eY5LgH', 'result_codes': {'transaction': 'tx_failed', 'operations': ['op_no_issuer']}, 'result_xdr': 'AAAAAAAAAGT/////AAAAAQAAAAAAAAAG/////gAAAAA='}}
Things go Fishy while opr_change_trust
```

**Update**

It seems that the account is removed. Why?

Comment: Can you explain why you are depending on an asset-issuing account on testnet that you don't appear to control?

Comment: Because we are still testing the application hence on TestNet

Comment: Sure, but if you're testing, isn't the issuing account yours? In which case, don't you know if you merged it or not?

Comment: Issue account is mine but why would I merge it?

Answer (score 1):

The account is now around: https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org/accounts/GCZDLM6KBK7P42JB6ONIZNYXE24G72PWUXLOZBOLE5EEGOC2FUKKIN4R

---

By any chance, if an account "suddenly" disappears, the only possibility is that the account is being merged into another one.

[EDIT: credit to @sui, one more possibility is "testnet reset", which happens once in a while...more precisely, once in a few months - https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/test-net.html#best-practices-for-using-testnet]

---

Note: any account can merge **only when** there is no trustline and offers related to it on the entire network.

Comment: I did not get the last line: Do you say it gets merged when there is no activity?

Comment: The other possibility for an account to disappear is a testnet reset.

Comment: @sui, sure, but the upcoming one is set in late April...unlikely for this case, but worthwhile to mention

Comment: @Volatil3 there is no auto-merge. Someone made it happen, or at least triggered it